# what causes this strange painting "corruption"?

Tags: delphi

Our application is largely a single screen application.  When entering a certain mode, we hide the TRibbon and replace it with a TPanel that has some TSpeedButton components on it.  (see below).  ignore any unevenness, button captions, etc.

[image: OK]

After I go back to the normal mode and then come back to this special mode, something is corrupted.  Any suggestions what's happening?  Strangely, if i move the mouse over the buttons, the appearance of images changes.

[image: bad]

Comment: I've heard of this sort of thing happening due to low-quality video drivers. Try reducing hardware acceleration in your video settings.

Comment: Also, are you running this in a virtual machine? I'm asking because e.g. VMWare Player has screen update errors in the last couple of versions.

Comment: Can you workaround the issue by forcing a repaint after mode switch?

Comment: Apart from hiding the TRibbon and replacing it with a TPanel, what else do you change when entering the special mode? Maybe it is some setting/configuration that you only set when returning to normal mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you all.  found a way to fix it.

it's software for general use so if low quality video drivers are vulnerable to this problem, we needed to change things.

it was not on a VM; it was a Win7 computer.  good to know of the VMWare issues because I do use VMWare.

redrawing it didn't help but @David Heffernan's comment gave me an idea that got me an answer.  the idea was to paint the panel to a bitmap & write that bitmap to a file throughout the process.

```
  procedure WriteToolbarBitmapFile(sText:string);
  var
    bmp:TBitmap;
  begin
    bmp:=TBitmap.Create;
    try
      bmp.Width:=pnlIMToolbar.Width;
      bmp.Height:=pnlIMToolbar.Height;
      pnlIMToolbar.PaintTo(bmp.Canvas, 0, 0);
      bmp.SaveToFile('c:\tmp\' + FormatDateTime('hh-nn-ss', Now) + ', ' + sText + '.bmp');
    finally
      bmp.Free;
    end;
  end;
```

it directly became apparent that the problem was occurring when i tried to set the position of the panel having the problem (pnlIMToolbar) so as to make sure its position is above another control.  changed it so the other control position is set instead.